# Proof for radius of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, absolute-convergence

I have the following two problems related to ordinary differential equations (power series)

> a. Define the radius of convergence of a series
>   $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{n}(x-x_{0})}^n$ for general
>   $(a_{n})_{n\geq0}$.
>
> b. Let $\rho$ be the radius of convergence
>   $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{n}(x-x_{0})}^n$. Using only the definition
>   above, determine the radius of convergence of
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{a_{n}(x-x_{0})}^n}{n^3 \ln(n+2) e^{n}}$$
>
> as a function of $\rho$. Justify carefully your answer.

I have solved (a) as follows

$$\rho = \sup \{r > 0: a_{n} r^n \text{ bounded} \}$$

where, $r=(x-x_{0})$

How do I solve (b)?

Comment: From your definition of $\rho$, can you relate $r$ to your power series?

Comment: I have updated the question with $r$ defined. Thanks

Comment: The definition you have given is the basic correct one. However, as @Mattos pointed out in his comment, it is difficult to use the general definition in many contexts. You should perhaps have a look at the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem in order to find a more usable equivalent definition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments above, by the **Cauchy-Hadamard theorem** (see for example [1], chapter III §2 pp. 53-54) we have the following relation
$$
\rho = \sup \{r > 0: c_{n} r^n \text{ is bounded }\forall n\in\Bbb N \}
\iff \rho =\frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Let's apply the right side formula in the relation \eqref{1} in order to calculate the convergence radius $\rho^\prime$ of the power series 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{a_{n}(x-x_{0})}^n}{n^3 \ln(n+2) e^{n}}.
\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
We have that $c_n=a_n\big(n^3 \ln(n+2) e^{n}\big)^{-1}$ and thus
$$
\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}= \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{{|a_{n}|}}{|n^3 \ln(n+2) e^{n}|}}
$$
and since $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{{|n^3 \ln(n+2) e^{n}|}}=e$ and $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{{|a_{n}|}}=\rho^{-1}$
$$
\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\frac{1}{\rho e}\iff \rho^{\prime}=\rho e
$$

[1] Robert B. Burckel (1979), "*[An Introduction to Classical Complex Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=beSXZhrfDngC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=true)*", Vol. 1, Lehrbücher und Monographien aus dem Gebiete der exakten Wissenschaften. Mathematische Reihe, Band 64, Basel–Stuttgart: Birkhäuser Verlag, p. 570, ISBN 3-7643-0989-X, [DOI:10.1007/978-3-0348-9374-9](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-9374-9), [MR0555733](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0555733), [Zbl 0434.30001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0434.30001).

Answer (score 2):

By [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) we know that$$r{=\text{radius of convergence}\\=\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_{n+1}(x-x_0)^{n+1}\over a_{n}(x-x_0)^{n}}\\=(x-x_0)\cdot\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_{n+1}\over a_{n}}}$$therefore for (b) we have$$r{=(x-x_{0})\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{{a_{n+1}}}{(n+1)^3 \ln(n+3) e^{n+1}}\cdot \frac{n^3 \ln(n+2) e^{n}}{a_n}\\={x-x_0\over e}\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}{a_{n+1}\over a_n}}$$